# fancytree does not create unique keys

Tags: key, unique, fancytree

My first tries with fancytree lead to this problem:

(1) I create a tree with the following data:

```
var SOURCE = [{"expanded":true,"key":"_1","title":"room",
               "children":[{"key":"_2","title":"child1"}]}]
```

Everything looks as expected.

(2) I add a node with:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree")
      var activeNode = tree.getNodeByKey("_1"); 

      activeNode.setActive();
      activeNode.addChildren({
        title: "newChild"
      });
  });
```

(3) I want to see the new tree:

```
var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");
var jdata = JSON.stringify(tree.toDict());
```

(4) And this the representation:

```
[{"expanded":true,"key":"_1","title":"room",
  "children":[
     {"key":"_2","title":"child1"},
     {"key":"_1","title":"newChild"}
  ]
}]
```

Seems to be ok, but the newChild got the key "_1", which is not unique.
​What is wrong​?

​Regards, Martin​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancytree generates *missing* keys using this pattern: `“_<sequence>”`, but does not check for uniqueness.
You can either omit keys altogether or choose a different pattern for the keys you pass.